# Error with HTMLParser and feed in Python

Tags: python-3.x, html-parsing

Hello I am using Python3 to create an application which from a given URL it returns the text of the website without the HTML tags, just clean and plain text.

Here is my code is supposed to work but is not:

```
import urllib, formatter, sys
from urllib.request import urlopen
from html.parser import HTMLParser

website = urlopen("http://www.google.com")
data = website.read()
website.close()

format = formatter.AbstractFormatter(formatter.DumbWriter(sys.stdout))
ptext = HTMLParser(format)
ptext.feed(data)
ptext.close()
```

The error:

```
  File "app.py", line 11, in <module>
    ptext.feed(data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/html/parser.py", line 144, in feed
    self.rawdata = self.rawdata + data
TypeError: Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly
```

I do find a solution which overcome the error but I don't get the appropriate result. The solution was to change the following line:

> ptext.feed(data)

to:

> ptext.feed(data.decode("utf-8"))

The problem now is that there is no outcome to the terminal the program is run but there is no outcome, the code is tested on a tutorial I saw and it works.

Thanks.